# WPF updating dynamically created buttons with dynamically created contextmenu items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls

I am new to WPF and I am struggling with following thing:

I am creating dynamically buttons and adding them to grid, then I want to give them contextmenu which i am doing, but here is the thing contextmenu consists of integers and now when I click integer from contextmenu, I would like to update buttons content with number chosen from this contextmenu how do I achieve it?

Help and explainations will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
     List<int> a = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            a.Add(i + 1);

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.ItemsSource = a;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
            {

                btn = new Button() {ContextMenu=menu };
                btn.Width = 25;
                btn.Height = 25;
                btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                MyGrid.Children.Add(btn);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do 4 steps to archieve it :

1. Add a member variable to record which button you right click to show
   contextmenu:

   `private Button currentBtn;`
2. Add event to record the current right click button:

   `btn.MouseRightButtonUp += (cbtn, e2) => { currentBtn = cbtn as Button; };`
3. Define menuitem:

   `List<MenuItem> a = new List<MenuItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        var item = new MenuItem();
        item.Header = (i + 1).ToString();
        item.Click += item_Click;
        a.Add(item);
    }`
4. Add click event to menuitem:

   `void item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (currentBtn != null)
       {
           var i = sender as MenuItem;
           Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { currentBtn.Content = i.Header; });
       }
   }`

Comment: Thank you it helps, however first I was thinking about making MenuContext for each button, then binding MenuItems to button, is it good way? If yes could u show how to bind from code, it would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to make a MenuContext for each button, you probably have to create a Collection (Data table/Dictionary) to store the mapping between them. Then you can retrieve each MenuContext's button from the collection. But I don't know whether Binding can achieve this. However, I don't think making a MenuContext for each button is a good idea. You don't need so many MenuContext.